# Thumbnail Caption hover effect in bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-hover

I want to have caption hover effect in thumbnail and for this i did coding like this

```js
$(document).ready (function() {

$ ('.thumbnail').hover(
    function( ) {
    $ (this).find ('.caption').slideDown(250); //.fadeIn(250)
},
function( ) {
$ (this).find ('.caption').slideUp(250); //.fadeOut(205)
}
);
});
```

```css
.thumbnail {
position:relative;
overflow:hidden;
}

.caption {
position:absolute;
top:0;
right:0;
background:RGB( 5, 5, 5) ;
color:#FFFFFF;
text-align:center;
z-index:2;
width:100%;
height:100%;
padding:2%;
display:none;
}

<div class="col-sm-4">
  <div class="thumbnail">
  <img src="two.jpg" alt="two" class="align-center img-responsive">
  <div class="caption">
  <h3>Women's Clothing</h3>
 <p>Shop Now !</p>
 <p><a href="" class="label label-danger" title="Shop Now"></a>
  </div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="col-sm-4">
  <div class="thumbnail">
  <img src="three.jpg" alt="three" class="align-center img-responsive">
  <div class="caption">
  <h3> Juniors Clothing</h3>
      <p>Shop Now !</p>

      </div>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-4">
  <div class="thumbnail">
    <div class="caption">
     <h3>Men's Clothing</h3>
       <p>Shop Now !</p>
   </div>
 <img src="one.jpg" alt="one">
</div>
</div>

<div class="col-sm-4">
  <div class="thumbnail">
  <img src="two.jpg" alt="two" class="align-center img-responsive">
  <div class="caption">
  <h3>Women's Clothing</h3>
 <p>Shop Now !</p>
 <p><a href="" class="label label-danger" title="Shop Now"></a>
  </div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="col-sm-4">
  <div class="thumbnail">
  <img src="three.jpg" alt="three" class="align-center img-responsive">
  <div class="caption">
  <h3> Juniors Clothing</h3>
      <p>Shop Now !</p>

      </div>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

On image when i take mouse it only shows text but thumbnail.hover function of slide up and down is not showing.

Anyone have any clue what is it that i am doing wrong as per coding.

Comment: For starters, you have lots of spaces in your syntax where there shouldn't be spaces. E.g., `$ (this)` should be `$(this)`

Comment: thanks i fixed spaces but still it is not working sliding up and down

Comment: Fix your question to show your fixed code

Comment: i fixed code in the post also.

Answer (score 1):

It was a problem with your CSS. See below:

```
.caption {
position:absolute;
top:0;
left:0;
background-color:rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.58);
color:#FFFFFF;
text-align:center;
z-index:2;
width:180px;
height:90px;
padding:10px;
display:none;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/a7m2ce7u/1/

Comment: i tried that it brings text little bit in the center but the curtain effect which slides down and slides up is still not showing

Comment: after changing background RGB at least now it is showing black curtain but it hides now image when hover over image how i can give transparent color to curtain so that image is also visible through transparent

Comment: Did you try the fiddle? It works - you need to carefully look at the changes in the CSS. The rule is `rgba(r, g, b, a)` NOT `rgb(r, g, b, a)`

Comment: yeah i know that was the problem but now i am struggling with how to make it white transparent so that image can be seen through it.

Comment: ok finally fixed it. rgba(255,255,255,1)then it will make white transparent

Comment: In rgba(255,255,255,1), the 1 is the alpha. 1 is full opacity, opaque. 0 is completely transparent. So you probably want somewhere in the middle, like 0.5